# Unable to get element text with PowerShell

Tags: html, css, powershell

I'm trying to get player names from the scoring table on http://www.pgatour.com/leaderboard.html page, but searching for it with getElementsByTagName using PowerShell returns nothing:

```
$HTML = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://www.pgatour.com/leaderboard.html
$HTML.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("a") | where { $_.className -like '*expansion*' }
```

Searching for class name in web browser's developer tools using **.name.expansion** CSS selector returns player names that I need, but as far as I know there is no way to search using CSS selector in PowerShell.

I also tried to use *$HTML.AllElements*, but with no luck.

Please advise on what is the best way to resolve this task. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't get same page in powershell, as in browser. To check it, try the code:

```
$HTML = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://www.pgatour.com/leaderboard.html"
$HTML.Content > leaderboard.html
```

Then open leaderboard.html in browser. As you can see, there is message

> It appears your browser may be outdated. For the best website
>   experience, we recommend updating your browser.

And leaderboard is missing. What you can try, is to get content via IE

```
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application 
#$ie.visible=$true
$ie.navigate("http://www.pgatour.com/leaderboard.html") 
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100} #waiting for page is ready
start-sleep -s 30 #waiting for leaderboard to load
$ahrefs = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")
$names = ($ahrefs | where {$_.className -eq "name expansion"})
$names | foreach {write-host $_.textContent}
```

Note, the solution above is extremely slow

Comment: By the way, why am I not getting the same page in PS? Is something wrong with the page itself?

Comment: I guess it because PS doesn't have javascript and not all dynamic content can be rendered